# How to kill a marine in power armor?

Tags: science-fiction, military

So there is a riot. This is not a normal riot; it is a uber-ultra-mega riot. The rioters are armed with the best of 21st century rifle tech and whatever they could make at home -- i.e. Molotov cocktails, flaming bricks and various clubs. The marines are under orders to peacefully dispel the riot using tasers, shields and tear gas. They are wearing 4A+ power armor which will protect them from: fire, almost all small arms fire, stabs, and beatings. It makes you stronger and faster. That said they are not invulnerable; continued fire will break armor. How to kill them with the rioters' weapons?

Comment: Does the power armor protect from bullet impact shocks? What if it's hit with .50 BMG round?

Comment: This question seems in very poor taste considering recent events.

Comment: You’ll live but that section of the amour will be pretty messed up. The marines are deployed without their normal countermeasures so if you get shot at no blocking it. Serious bruises in the morning.

Comment: Well @user535733 I can’t just rewrite a couple chapters just cause some idiots did some stupid stuff.

Comment: If there are too many rioteres, such marines could be taken down just by bare hands. Once marine is immobolised and kiked down no armor will save him from being ripped to pieces if poeple are angry enough. Protection gear could give some time for the resque, but in the end some guy with welding equipment will get the job done.

Comment: Jesus Christ.... That is a scary thought might include that actually.

Comment: The other consideration is the "power" part of the power armor - does it actually give the user a super strength?

Comment: Also, "fire protection" in real life does not mean "0 damage from fire" like in video games. Fire protection suits protect from exposure to fire only for some time, and certain temperatures.

Comment: @11Bravo, actually if it is [really cool power armor](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Power_Armour), like in Warhammer 40k universe, there is no consern about many angry people. Welders are still a threat, but rioters usually never own [such welders](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Melta_weapon). There might be some balance issues with existence of such power armor, though.

Comment: Related question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/180294/862

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without more details on the power armor. It is what gives the marine an advantage and will essentially make or break the combat scenario. What are it's parameters, weaknesses? Is it like 40k combat armor where it makes you a virtually invincible god that can fight for days without end, or is it like Fallout power armor that has a relatively short window of activity?

Comment: Just ask WWED.... "what would Ewoks do"?

Comment: Molotov cocktail...

Answer (score 4):

As a rioter, you have a few options.

Some of you might have similar experiences: you are driving your car, and suddenly you realize that it's basically a violent 1-ton battering ram propelled forwards by a continuous series of explosions, and caution is advised when handling one. On the other hand, if your police is currently power armored and in the way of progress (or what you hope is progress), you might consider using your car. If you want extra creativity points: a disgruntled employee once bolted a bunch of steel to his bulldozer and rampaged through cars, houses and other street features, a power armored policeman won't be a problem.

Speaking of battering, home-made explosives! For some reason you can still buy books online without repercussions on how to make explosives from household chemicals. Even if the explosion itself doesn't break the armor, its shockwave and potential spalling effect could break the servo's and policeman inside. The only 2 reasons I don't have a copy is because I don't have anything I want to blow up enough (and likely never will), and that creating explosives in your kitchen is likely to kill you with chemicals absorbed in the skin, spread through the air or currently exploding because you made a mistake in the quantities or handling them.

Hit their fuel supplies and exhaust them. These power armors likely need some fuel or rather special energy sources, likely swapping batteries so they can be charged. Either hit these instead or try to keep power armor engaged in maneuvering long enough that they run out of power or fuel. You can attempt to delay them by the time they return to fuel, then taking them down when they are helpless.

Hit the joints. While armored legs and joints are much more well protected than wheels or tracks ever can be, they'll likely still offer some opportunities for small-arms to hinder the system. The kneecap likely has its armor, but hitting the rear of the knee with an armor-piercing round should be able to get you results. If only the result of said policeman turning around with a limp and pacifying you, or his buddies doing it for you and not giving anyone else a chance to do the same. Remember, even if you get a shot actually hitting something as small as a kneecap from a range where power armor wont immediately be able to stop you isn't going to be easy.

Civil disobedience. Its easy to find a rioter, but what are you going to do when large parts of the civilian chain that keep the policemen happy stop serving them? No more repairs to their houses or vehicles, refused to be sold any food or drink, being socially shunned, electronic services like their email stops functioning etc. The only paths forwards are either increasing violence and authoritarianism (and current orders are specifically peacefully stopping the riots where they can), or the other path is negotiation to come to a solution and stop the riots.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of methods.  Depends on how much prep, what the conditions are, how close you can get to them, and how many rioters dead you are willing to accept.

"You cannae break the laws of physics captain!" Otherwise known as "what happens when you drop a wrench on a submarine."  If you smack him hard enough then his more dense internal body parts will squish up against the inside of the armor. His brain will smack the inside of his skull. And so on. Even in perfectly form-fitting armor, an impact equivalent to about a 10 story fall is extremely likely to kill him. That's not a particularly big bomb. If he can be pushed off a 10 story building (or equivalent) and can't fly, it's bad news.

Microwaves or other electromagnetic effects. One presumes there is a bunch of conducting metal in his armor if it really is powered somehow. Wrap him in copper wire and connect it the the main power supply, he's a solenoid. At the very least it is likely to melt his radio equipment and set his hair on fire.

Ultra-sound likely goes through the armor. The right kind of ultra-sound (maybe not available to the typical impromptu rioter, but the ring leaders might well have it) could fry his brains.

Various caustic chemicals can mess with the joints. It has to be flexible in some way. One presumes he has some kind of rubber or plastic or something making the joints. It might be as simple as drain cleaner.

If you can set him on fire he may cook in the can. Does he notice right away if you put    fire on his backpack? That is probably where his power supply is. Maybe by the time he does notice (Do you smell something burning?) he has to panic remove the armor.  How does his power supply react to being on fire?

Answer (score 2):

**Do not kill them.  Incapacitate them.**

While the marine is distracted, a rioter loops a rope around its leg.  Suddenly the marine is pulled backward with the rope by a team of persons.  When off balance other ropes are looped around arms, legs and head.  The power armor is tied against a building with nylon ropes and steel cable, which were brought for rappelling purposes but are plenty strong.

Once the marine is tied securely, a hat can be placed on his head and a mustache drawn on his face plate, and rioters can take selfies with him.

Answer (score 2):

This questions reminds me of that old sea shanty,

What to do to kill a marine in combat armor, Oh what to do to kill a marine in combat armor, Oh what to do to kill a marine in combat armor, early in the morning?

Oh pick him or her up and drop him or her off the tallest building, Oh pick him or her up and drop him or her off the tallest building, Oh pick him or her up and drop him or her off the tallest building, early in the morning.

Oh hack his or her suit's environmental controls and turn off his or her oxygen, Oh hack into his or her suits computer and turn off his or her oxygen, early in the morning.

Oh hoist him up in chains and hold him or her over a thermite fire, Oh hoist him or her up in chains and dangle him or her over a thermite fire, Oh hold them over a thermite fire, early in the morning.

Comment:  Oh incapacitate them and remove the armor, incapacitate them and remove the armor, incapacitate them and remove the armor earlay in the morning! 

Comment: Oh how do you do anything like these things? How do you do anything like these things? How do you do anything like these things if the armor fights baaaack?

Answer (score 1):

### Orchestrated Evil:

Great ideas everyone. I love the idea of using a car (or bulldozer). Electricity is really good, especially if you entangle the suit in conductive mesh first. And fire resistant is not infinity capacity to absorb heat, so sustained application of masses of propellant is a wonderful idea (I imagine dragging an immobilized trooper to a gas station and cooking him slowly). I do have a couple of things to add, mostly centered on the idea that if you immobilize and blind, the most powered suit in the world is useless. They also all assume a riot much more carefully orchestrated than a mere angry mob is going to be able to manage.

- Suits are likely heavy. Given enough prepping, a pit filled with (name your horror - gelled gasoline, crude oil or a thick industrial substance filled with grit?) could be used - lure an armored person into falling in, then they can't see, possibly can't move, may be on fire in a sustained way, and being mobbed by enemies.
- Ultra-riots mean structural damage. Literally drop a house (or multi-story building) on them.
- Glue guns: If there is mass-rioting, police weapons have likely been seized. Glue guns encase victims in a mass of sticky, tough material that makes everything stick to them, make them stick to everything, would blind, jam weapons, etc. An improvised glue bomb could even be made, splattering a whole team.
- Monofilament wire: You likely have some high-tech materials lying around in your near future. A spool of monofilament could be just the trick. lay out a mass of the stuff and it would be hard to spot. Get a suit to run into it at high speed and entangle them so they can't move. Various other materials and meshes could be used to perform the same trick.
- As an addendum to the car and bomb thing, did anyone mention a good old fashioned car bomb? Two nasty things that get nastier together.
- If you are willing to move into an industrial setting, the fiendishness goes off the scale. Lasers, cutting torches, arc furnaces, molten  metal, industrial presses - all can be used to make very lethal traps. Ultimate irony would be crushing a suit of powered armor in a press molding powered armor.

Comment: I don’t know how I would move the press but yeah that would be ironic. But wait what if it is a full body press they would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

**It's Going to Be Tough, For Story Reasons if Nothing Else**

The field of riot control is based on a tacit understanding that lethal force will not be used by either side. The definition of "lethal force" in the context of someone in power armor can vary, but unless the Marine's chain of command values the lives of their troops less than the individuals in the crowd who have made specific, explicit preparations to kill them (a tough sell to the troops, as I'm sure you can imagine) the entire situation moves from "riot control" to "combat" in a hurry.

The tougher your marines are (and it sounds like they are very tough indeed), the more preparation will be required to injure/kill them, and the more that preparation is going to make the individual with lethal intent stand out in the crowd (Molotov cocktails are concealable and portable, welding equipment or impromptu Panzerfausts less so). Though with strong enough armor something as seemingly fatal as "parking a truck on them" could still fall in non-lethal territory.

Assuming the power armor lacks "point defense" equipment (reactive charges, "electric fencing", chemical dispensers etc.), it would be possible for the rioters to blind/swarm/immobilize/otherwise render combat ineffective the marines and trap them in their armor. The design of the armor itself can't be ignored in that case; armor intended for the battlefield would be designed to resist long range weapons fire, while armor intended for riot control would be designed to prevent immobilization, with extra paneling to prevent insertion of hands, crowbars etc. into vital areas (seen today in the difference between ballistic plate carriers and full-body riot control armor). The focus on incapacitation would prevent the conflict from moving into lethal territory, within which it seems the marines would easily win if only through liberal application of the "drop trooper's handshake"--grabbing an exposed body part of an unarmored individual and giving it a good squeeze (ouch!).

It's this answerer's opinion that any exploited weaknesses will need to be strategic ("there's too many of them") or zero-day in nature ("we never thought of this"). Something as simple as paint sprayed over a visor could do the trick. But in the arms race of technologically advanced government vs. mildly organized rioters, with both given equal opportunity to prepare and in a (generally) less-than-lethal context, it defies belief to think that the rioters will win.

Comment: It might be easier to explain if the conveniently available armor is optimized for all-out combat rather than for crowd control, so the armor might contain very high-power weaponry, but the marines would be barred from using it in this scenario. It will take a couple of days to re-configure the armor with less-lethal munitions or to acquire built-for-purpose crowd-control armor like police forces use.

Comment: ^Strong tack. And unless the armor is set up to be reconfigurable (which means cost + complexity) no number of days will help you. It's possible you could swap out your (ballistic) ceramite armor for (riot-control) fiber-reinforced hyper plastic panels. Armor panels are expected to be damaged and so must be at least armory-replaceable, but it presumes those panels exist in an accessible form. Shields and less-lethal melee weapons should be relatively accessible on any world with a police force, and support roles (CS gas, fire fighting, etc.) could be performed by officers in normal riot gear.

Answer (score 0):

Use tactics!

The thing is I don't see this as a problem since a marine in power armor is not superman and his training and tactics would mostly be the same as without PA.

**The biggest problem is this**

Sure with PA you can be all parade like and stand in the middle of the street looking regal and shiny. But once bullets start flying that marine's training is taking over and he is diving towards cover and using tactics that is drilled into him to resolve the situation.

Marines would just do what they know to achieve their goals. The added protection of PA can of course work in certain situations but would mostly be balanced by the risks involved since any officer can quickly and accurately optimize a course of action.

Example:
Rioters are attempting to break into a position you are ordered to defend. That place might be your base or the residence of the president or Dunkin' Donuts for all that matters. As a soldier you obey orders.
Anyway the rioters are coming in with clubs and flag and knives...etc.
That situation you are still in danger if you engage them in CQC but still your own PA offers enough protection that you can engage the closest and most daring offender. You have order to peacefully resolve the situation so your course of action is to relay on your PA and show enough controlled aggression to deter the rest of the crowd.

But if you are just protecting your thing and bullets start flying you dive behind the sandbags, shoulder your M16 and laying down a hail of fire at the source of incoming fire before you can even realize what happened. You are a soldier.
That's what the army drills into them.

So. Even with the idea of "The marines are under orders to peacefully dispel the riot using tasers, shields and tear gas"

Only works as far as the rioters do not bring their own automatic rifles or at least use them. **If the rioters start shooting you really can't stop any soldier in the world from returning fire.**

So. What you have is a skirmish type of situation. Where the rioters attack the marine and both sides have their safety off. Of course marines won't just relay on small arms because the does not deal in anything **but** overkill. Citizens or your local variety terrorists once the bullets start flying the soldiers are hopping into their tanks, IFVs, and ordering a drone strike but I digress.

Anyway I'm not sure if that is a frame challenge or not but I just think this is the most logical course of action for soldiers anywhere every single time.

With that being said you can just use stuff like: Armor piercing rounds, grenades, sustained fire, higher caliber rounds...etc.

Again coordinating the attacks and trying to isolate small groups marines in a building then just shooting thousands upon thousand of rounds on them is pretty much the only thing you can do. You are not gonna send your agile PA armored melee units to counter them.

So. Take a page out of the army's book and just throw absurd amounts of bullets at them. If a bullet does 1% damage to them you just need to fire a thousand at them.

But without a command coordinating those attacks and officers on the ground adapting to the battle the marines would 9/10. But again I digress.

So. It all boils down to not what technology are you using but what tactics are you using. Sun Tzu would still be applicable here as he ever was

Lastly I'm not sure about the rest of your story or world so I'm not judging. But if this is the US then don't think the US army can be called upon to intervene in internal affairs even for peace keeping stuff. But I could be wrong.

Comment: As far as I know military personell gets things like force cards. These have the instructions with how much force they are allowed to react and how they are allowed to escalate them. They might dive for cover but they won't just shoulder their M16 and lay into a crowd. They would still follow orders, and if the force cards say "don't just kill everyone", they'll be going to obey that and escalate violence in order of the cards. First X verbal and signal warnings, then smoke, then raised weapons, then shots into the ground, then debilitating gas etc etc all before opening fire on select targets

Comment: @Demigan,
Maybe if you read it then it makes more sense.
"Only works as far as the rioters do not bring their own automatic rifles or at least use them. If the rioters start shooting you really can't stop any soldier in the world from returning fire."
Yes. I'm saying they follow orders. But I'm also saying that there is not a soldier in existence that can get shot at and do nothing.

Comment: That is exactly my point: they will not all immediately return fire, but follow the force escalation they have been given in order to pacify the enemy. Especially in this situation that is more likely due to the amount of civilians without weapons that will also be around.

Comment: @Demigan,
I don't know where you found soldiers who stand in the open getting shot at from automatic rifles and don't return fire. The whole force escalation thing is meaningless once automatic rifles start shooting. Ask any soldier in existence. They just don't take kindly to been shot at from rifles. 
I think you have some romantic ideas about marines to think they will just stand still and take incoming fire that is capable of murdering them. Which is hilarious given how we saw certain police personal act recently in the US. 
Anyway, again, Once the firing starts all bets are off

Comment: I think you have a far more violent idea of marines or soldiers. For one if they detect rifles they wont be standing out in the open depite their armor. Secondly the point of firing is to stop your opponent from firing, but there are far better ways to make these civilians stop. If you fire into the crowd you will have more death on your hands and galvanize the rioters to be more violent in return. If you pacify them with warnings and slowly escalate your force with shots in the air/ground to avoid escalation by direct lethal force you have a better chance of succeeding

Comment: Its not romanticising, its logical and even human to not instantly murder people. And soldiers get these orders, both general and specific, to reach their goals. An example of how they work can be found here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/pdf/OLH_2015_Ch5.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiZ-4Syt5juAhWICOwKHZ1jDy0QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1u3apl8fwXvr4hMKCTWVCe

Comment: @Demigan,
I don't think we are on the same page since I already addressed this point and gave an example of how soldiers can deal with a situation that is dangerous but not to the point of coming under continues fire and not returning it. 
So. I'm sure we are talking about different things even though you think that I'm saying soldier will murder people for the slightest reason while I'm just saying that soldiers won't stand around and get murdered.
I really think we are talking about different things here.

Comment: you did not adress this point, you just repeated what you thought would happen. You quite literally said these soldiers would immediately start using IFV's and drone strikes against the civilians! That is in no way realistic. Yes soldiers are trained to kill, but not to kill indiscriminately or to kill immediately. Read parts of that link I send you, following those Rules of Engagement are just as much part of training as killing is. Even professional soldiers are best pacified so they surrender. RoE is vital, and soldiers will not instantly fire into civilians when those fire.

Comment: @Demigan,
Maybe if you bothered reading you won't just make a straw man argument against me. 
I say soldiers will respond with fire once fired at.
You are constantly choosing to make this: "ah you are wrong and saying soldiers just kill people which is wrong"
Even then I say "once the bullets start flying" And you ignore it.
I say "You have order to peacefully resolve the situation " But you ignore it.
That is why I wanted to have a reasonable discussion without cherry picking my argument and just taking stuff out of context and replaying to them like that's something.

Comment: no strawmen, I'm saying that ESPECIALLY when the bullets start flying that these soldiers will not immediately use lethal force. This is why in EVERY SINGLE ONE of my comments I mention that the civilians are firing or the soldiers are returning fire (which means the civilians are already firing). Talk about cherry picking. You talk about the orders and say that once bullets start flying those orders go right out the window. That just isnt true.

Comment: @Demigan,
I spoke of the escalation of force already. But at a certain point you insist that your soldiers won't return fire. Like I say: Yes. without deadly danger they won't hurt civilians. But I'm also saying that at a certain point when the danger of literally dying is too high they will defend themselves. 
Not sure how many variations of the same piece of information I need to say. Like am I supposed to produce a 300 pages manual of the situation? 
The cherry picking is in ignoring the set parameters and focusing and refusing 1 point despite it being set in a chain of actions

Comment: when all warnings and non-lethal options have failed, yes the soldiers will return fire in a measured response. However your "escalation" starts at "shoot into civilians as soon as the first shot is fired because no soldier would not do that if fired upon". You then go on to say that they will use drone strikes and IFV's, armed with .50cal machine guns at minimum and all the way up to 105mm canons, against civilian crowds. You might as well start with chemical weapons and tactical nukes at that point. No 300 pages needed, just a reasonable escalation with measured violent response.

Comment: @Demigan,
1/2
It is your choice to view the scenario as bad just because I did not word it like want it. I honestly have no control over that. Now What you are consistently failing to consider is how hectic firefights are. You seem to have a video games idea of reality where soldier are under fire that threats their live and they merely only engage with their own small arms. Such an engagement is more or less equal which equals higher causality rates because that is how things work. If both sides have small arms then a lot of both sides die. 
Now tell me what marines company likes to die?

Comment: actually its the other way around. I'm basing it on what I heard and know about how soldiers reacted in Iraq and Afghanistan, where it wasnt even their own civilians. Yes firefights are hectic, which is exactly why these force-escalation procedures are created. To give guidelines on how much force they can use and in which order to use them. you do not use IFV's because several people inside a crowd are firing, nor do you go full-auto. Just read the link I gave you which is real-life, while you use "I think this is what soldiers do".

Comment: @Demigan,
Seems to be you are just letting your own personal experience color your opinions. When you were sitting with your buddies I'm sure they won't tell you about Abu Gharib or war crimes that tends to happen. 
How much stuff did the US army drop on Vietnam? A google search says "More than 270 million submunitions were dropped"
Afghanistan? 
7423 weapons in 2019
https://www.statista.com/chart/16079/weapons-released-by-the-us-coalition-over-afghanistan/
There too "the United Nations announced that Afghan and U.S. forces killed more civilians in the first half of 2019 than insurgents"

Comment: yes those things happen too. Which is why the RoE exists in the first place. The article quite literally states this happened due to a change in the RoE! Just because the Trump administration ramped up the more indiscriminate air(!)bombing campaign does not mean the RoE was far stricter before in order to reduce those very civilian casualties in the first place! Its a literal proof of concept showing how important the PROPER RoE is.

Comment: @Demigan,
Perfect example of how to drag a conversation out to useless territory.

Comment: how is that so? Up untill now I've been on point: you proclaim ultra-violent marines, I say that they will escalate force much slower. I've provided a link as example, your own link actually helps prove it by showing different results due to different RoE's. Considering the non-lethal orders given a much slower escalation of violence will be their standard of RoE. No marines jumping behind cover and returning fire at soon as the first shots fly.

Comment: @Demigan,
I mean your choice to view my answer as so and so. 
I suppose this is starting to get political as first you are drawing your argument from your army buddies. Second your refusal to acknowledge the acts committed by US army, my source is the UN which is even corrupt lmao, and choosing to view the UN words that says the US army killed more civilians than militants are proof that your army buddies are the greatest most civil people even against actual enemies. Even when my whole point was about self preservation. 100% self preservation not violent marines. Honestly smh

Comment: you are using air-dropped bombs as a reference for how homebound marines would function and ignoring that the rise of casualties was SPECIFICALLY BECAUSE of the changes in the RoE. I dont see a reason to discuss your idea's of corruption if both my and your sources point to the chosen RoE being vital.

Comment: @Demigan, 
You are the one who quoted the conduct of your army buddies in wars oversees. Why is it ok for you to bring it to the table and not me?
And every single time I mentioned the literal survival of your marine you ignore it to continue your patriotic ideas about the perfect conduct of your soldiers. 
Again ignoring I said they will only return fire when their is at danger. 
Sir we lost 20% of our men. 
It's cool. We don't have orders to engage. 
sire we lost 50%.
RoE states not returning fire.
Sir the president is under fire. 
Our RoE ouch my chest.

Comment: Actually you didn't. Every time you tried to say something like that you immediately returned to "they'll just murder the lot". Ofcourse when you start taking casualties you'll be at a point where you'll start firing accurately. However even then RoE takes effect: How much force will you use? Do you shoot with intent to kill or harm? How many salvo's before you check the effect? Will you shoot at armed men retreating or not? Doing so could be beneficial, or galvanize them to come back or escalate the violence in another situation.

Comment: @Demigan,
You can view my answer as a frame challenge or different perspective. You can even think this is wrong. But the persistence of discussing such a hypothetical scenario makes me think that it's just weird. I just think you got angry because I did not praise your army friends enough. After all this is my opinion, the answer, and the comment is your opinion.

Comment: I don't have army friends and I'm not angry. I'm pointing out that your answer is flat out wrong and use proof for that. You keep returning to the discussion and say that somehow it's different and repeat your same argument.

Comment: @Demigan
Flat out wrong in your opinion. Ftfy

Comment: flat out wrong factually. A power-armored marine armed with non-lethal weapons and orders to peacefully dispel the rioters will not have an RoE that includes "use airstrikes and IFV's on the crowd". There will not be a squadron of aircraft standing by as that is not expected. To even gain access to them the higher in command need to give clearance, even if your marines wanted to they couldnt use them yet. Things have to go incredibly bad before anyone is going to consider bombing their own civilians.

Comment: @Demigan,
Flat out refusing to do anything to do keep repeating your argument and clinging to your opinion. 
Truly a discussion worthy of this site

Comment: thats the point: its not an opinion. Its like I'm saying "1+1=2" and when you say the answer is actually 3, you then ask me to not repeat my answer. Both my and your own sources quite literally show that I am right, you had to misinterpret data about AIR BOMBING and apply it to power-armored marines with non-lethal weapons in order to get your argument to make sense. In your own words: truly a lack of discussion worthy of this site.

Comment: @Demigan,
It's how you interpret the facts and put them into a view that is your opinion. It's like saying 1+1=2. And since this is a fact our hamburgers are the best in the world. And when questioned you say: But 1+1=2 and it's a fact

Comment: fact: Rules of engagement (RoE) is leading in how marines react. Fact: using airbomb statistics as proof that marines would mow down civilians that fire on them is the best hamburger here. Fact: the situation described (non-lethally armed marines tasked with peacefully pacifying the civilians) there will not be an RoE that says "shoot the moment you get shot at with machine guns and IFV weapons". Fact: you tried to describe me as some american that worships the military, neither is true.

Comment: @Demigan, I kept trying to chill and have a reasonable discussion but when refuse to even consider anything I say and repeat what you think is true then the discussion is doomed. 
If you spent less time glorifying your marine and read what I said earlier, I will bracket that is USA USA USA "
how you interpret the facts and put them into a view that is your opinion" USA USA USA. Maybe that get you to pay attention to what I said. 
You see this is a fiction scenario. I'm not disagree that they will not respond with force...etc but I'm not an American so maybe I can't be right.

Comment: you are being hypocritical. Also I already told you I am not American, I would even classify America as a 3rd world nation that happened to hit the jackpot and become the richest in the world. It is closer to an Oliarchy/plutocracy with facistic elements with a broken political system that has bred a broken country. But despite that we can draw conclusions: RoE is important to its military, which is why when Trump changed the RoE to higher aggressions the amount of casualties immediately spiked. And if you agree with RoE being leading, why keep attacking me personally?

Comment: @Demigan, 
I "escalate" my aggression depending on the situation.
"hypocritical" I'd take it as an insult but I'm not even sure it fits. Like wth does it even mean here! 
You also seem to spend an awful amount of time try to make this answer wrong. I'm sure you already downvoted so I'm not sure who is taking this personal.
Anyway I like to get into these things from time to time which is going to be you say: Why do you yourself do it.
Last rom the first comment your refused to read what I wrote which makes it hilarious no gonna lie.
I get people love this here but it gets boring fast

Comment: Again, my first comment is on point and was based perfectly on what you wrote. I don't even know how I am supposed to have misread it. You said that they would fire on the crowd ASAP when some people in the crowd start firing at them and repeated that in your comment. I claim otherwise and both my and your proof shows this, which makes my first comment on point. I'm not interested in inspecting why either of us is invested in this that's even more of a waste of time.

Comment: @Demigan
Again your words hold no more power than they do.
You can say the same thing over and over again but that does not make it right or wrong.

Comment: your argument hasnt changed yet you expect a different answer from me? Doing the same thing and expecting different results and all that.

Answer (score 0):

### ⚡ Electricity ⚡

Overload those tasers, metal conducts electricity right? And that wasn't explicitly mentioned in the prompt, though it isn't the *rioter's* weapons but the marines'.

Pikachu - thunderbolt!

Comment: If the outer casing of the armor is conductive enough to let a taser work, wouldnt that outer casing also immediately ground the electricity into the ground harmlessly? There's no reason for the electricity to pass through the layers of armor, clothing and flesh when it can more easily travel through the metals.